# Where do I find the Toronto?

Tags: albion

Actually I am playing an old PC game called [Albion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albion_%28video_game%29) which is a really great game.

I already got the SEED, a thing needed to transform the space ship Toronto, but the problem is - I can't find that ship.

I have run through all of southern Umajo to find the ship, but it isn't there.
Several walk-throughs didn't help me at that point.

Can anyone help me, **please**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange at first, but the Toronto isn't actually physically on the Umajo map. You need to reach the [cave](http://albionworld.wikia.com/wiki/File:Map_242.png), path to which Ohl shows you, and leave it through the southern exit. Then walk a bit and you'll automatically enter the ship.

Edit:
You can't reach the Toronto from the southern part of Umajo. You have to return to the cave and take the **southern** exit (bottom of the map). If you don't know how to get there, check [this map](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/albionworld/images/3/33/Map_217.png/revision/latest?cb=20140801220756), the entrance to the cave is carved into one of those rock blocks at the bottom right.

Comment: unfortunatly this does not happen after i leave the cave to the southern exit

Comment: @Thariama And what happens instead? You already entered the ship when you were first in Umajo, so why can't you find it now (you have the Seed)?

Comment: yes, i have been there already and i have the seed now, but all i can do is walk around southern Umajo after i left the cave and nothing happens.

Comment: ok, i will send it later when i am at home

Comment: @Thariama Check my edit.

Comment: thx, i will check that out and get back to you

Comment: thx, very much!!! now i am able to finish the game *cheers*

Comment: @Thariama You're welcome. ☺

Comment: game finished - what a game!!

Answer (score 2):

Accodring to [this walkthrough](http://www.the-spoiler.com/RPG/Blue.byte/albion.5.html) :

> [Once you've recieved the seed,] when you are ready, you should return
>   to Toronto via the path which leads to the cave East of Umajo(The cave
>   that Ohl led you to). Enter it and make your way to Toronto. Once on
>   it, there is no return.

Comment: i have used this path. Now my guys are wandering around in southern Umajo, but there seems to be no ship.

Comment: There are three points this cave interconnects. Take the last one.